# How to remove an 'ill formated' view

Tags: document-library, powershell, list-view

My Document Library errors, when trying to go to its settings, or to create a view. It also errors, when accessed with SPD. The logs hint where the issue is:

> "Application error when access /_layouts/15/ViewType.aspx, Error=Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: s"

One of the things that comes up in logs just before the exception:

> "The view {F925A5E1-2D43-44B7-BA2C-E9D9F801E1E4} from list XXX is ill formated. Please remove it"

However, when listing all the views in XXX using PowerShell, or trying to delete this view, it appears that it doesn't exist?